# Excel VBA copy paste then format

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Hi and thank you for any help with this, currently I have code that copy and pastes text from a named range then I have code that formats it however the range needs to be dynamic, I have it just set to do where my first table shows but I have over 50 tables that will be copy and pasted over:

Here is my code for the Text to be copy and pasted over:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
              Application.ScreenUpdating = False
              Dim copySheet As Worksheet
              Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet
            
              Set copySheet = Worksheets("Auto")
              Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Final")
            
              copySheet.Range("Range1").Copy
              pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
              Application.CutCopyMode = False
              Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

Here is my code for the Formatting:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Final").Range("A1:E15").Columns.AutoFit
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Final").Range("A3:E3").Interior.Color = RGB(180, 198, 231)
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Final").Range("A19:D19").Merge
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Final").Range("A4:A18").Merge
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Final").Range("A4:A17").HorizontalAlignment = -4131
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Final").Range("A4:A17").VerticalAlignment = -4160
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Final").Range("A19:D19").Interior.ColorIndex = 48
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Final").Range("A3:E19").Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Final").Range("A3:E19").Borders.Color = vbBlack
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Final").Range("A3:E19").Borders.Weight = xlThin
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Final").Range("A3:E3").Font.Bold = True
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Final").Range("D4:E18", "E19").Style = "Currency"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Final").Range("E19").Font.Bold = True
End Sub
```

As you can see the code for the formatting is not dynamic but static, how would I make this dynamic, or how would I go about implementing this formatting into the text code so that it copys and pasted the text across and then formats it?

End result *should* look like:

[image]

Comment: What does "dynamic" means in this context? What logical connection is between the range to be pasted and the the cells to be formatted?

Comment: dynamic meaning the cell range, example "A1:A15" will have to change to "A18:A33" and so on down the page along with all the other given ranges in the formatting code. The text that has been copied and pasted, needs to be formatted once its pasted into the styles given in the formatting code. @FaneDuru

Comment: This is logic, but I am afraid you missed the second clarification question... In order to do what you need, **without knowing the dynamic ranges sizes and the necessary format after pasting**, you must set some rules about it. Something like: All the range columns must be Autofit, first four cells on the range third row must be colored in ..., first four cells of the 19th row must be merged (if the case, or the row must be calculated according to some algorithm...) and so on. Otherwise, only the word "dynamic" does not say **anything**...

Comment: @FaneDuru the format wanted after pasting has been given in my original question? and the range size doesnt change merely where in the speadsheet the cells will be for each persons. I have also added an image of what the final result *should* look like given the copy paste - format

Comment: I am driving now. But how could you show the format for a **dynamic**  range? How to apply it for a range having two rows?

Comment: Im sorry im not even sure I understand what you are asking and leading astray from the actual situation of which I am trying to solve..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229103/discussion-between-ranjar-and-faneduru).

Comment: Not possible when I am driving...

Comment: @FaneDuru Please dont text and drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a combination of [Offset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Offset) and [Resize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize)

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim copySheet As Worksheet, pasteSheet As Worksheet
    Dim ar, r, rng As Range
    
    ar = Array("Range1", "Range2", "Range3")
                   
    Set copySheet = Worksheets("Auto")
    Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Final")
                           
    For Each r In ar
        Set rng = pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0)
        copySheet.Range(r).Copy rng
        Call ApplyFormat(rng)
    Next
   
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    End Sub


Private Sub ApplyFormat(ByVal rng As Range)
    
    Set rng = rng.Cells(1, 1) ' top left corner
    rng.Resize(15, 5).Columns.AutoFit ' A1:E15
    
    With rng.Offset(2, 0).Resize(1, 5) ' A3:E3
        .Interior.Color = RGB(180, 198, 231)
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With
    
    With rng.Offset(18, 0).Resize(1, 4) ' A19:D19
        .Merge
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 48
    End With
    
    With rng.Offset(3, 0).Resize(15, 1) ' A4:A18
        .Merge
        .HorizontalAlignment = -4131
        .VerticalAlignment = -4160
    End With
    
    With rng.Offset(2, 0).Resize(17, 5).Borders  ' A3:E19
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Color = vbBlack
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    
    rng.Offset(3, 3).Resize(15, 2).Style = "Currency" ' D4:E18
    
    With rng.Offset(18, 4) ' E19
        .Style = "Currency"
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With
  
End Sub
```